# splitting sentence with numeric character after period

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I am using python3, trying to split a text with note numbers after the period:

```
text = "Reproduction now becomes posited as “natural” production.16 Fortunati joins Marx in a minute but crucial declension from usevalue to nonvalue. "
```

this is the closest sentence splitting regex I've gotten to that still works:

```
sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* +', text)
```

I'm basically lost w/r/t catching the numeric instance immediately after a period via regex. Any help in properly incorporating [0-9] into the expression? Thanks.

**edit** this is how it ideally is split:

```
sentences[0]= "Reproduction now becomes posited as “natural” production.16"
sentences[1]= " Fortunati joins Marx in a minute but crucial declension from usevalue to nonvalue."
```

Comment: Could you clearly show us the desired output from that sentence?

Comment: Something like so could work: `\.\d+\b`, but it is unclear if it is what you are after.

Comment: noted, updated the post with a bit more info

Comment: Try changing the last `+` to `*` to make spaces optional. However, that might affect splitting other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'.*?\.\d+|.+', text)
['Reproduction now becomes posited as “natural” production.16',
 ' Fortunati joins Marx in a minute but crucial declension ...']
```

If you are okay using third party module, you can use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which allow non-fixed-width look-around assertion, split on empty string:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.split(r'(?<=\.\d+\b)', text, flags=regex.VERSION1)
['Reproduction now becomes posited as “natural” production.16',
 ' Fortunati joins Marx in a minute but crucial declension ...']
```